# Is this valid SQL Server Update syntax?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, update, syntax

Today I was reading some of my database notes that were taken long time ago. And I saw this query:

```
UPDATE Sales.Orders
SET (shipcountry, shipregion, shipcity)=
(SELECT country, region, city
FROM Sales.Customers AS C
WHERE C.custid =Sales.Orders.custid)
WHERE custid IN
(SELECT custid FROM Sales.Customers WHERE country = 'USA');
```

I'm really unfamiliar with this syntax. But my note says it's "valid SQL Server update syntax". Is this true? SSMS can't parse it. When I tried to run it, I got this:

[image]

Also SQL Server's `UPDATE` documentation seems suggest that `(` is not allowed after the `SET` keyword. Anyway, I just want to confirm.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The syntax:

```
...
SET (shipcountry, shipregion, shipcity) =
    ( SELECT country, region, city 
      ...
    )
...
```

is **valid *SQL* syntax** but not valid SQL Server syntax. It has not yet been implemented in any version of it.

The `(expression1, expression2, ...)` is called Row constructor and it can be used in various places, e.g. in `WHERE / WHEN / HAVING` conditions, in `UPDATE .. SET` (as your question), in `VALUES (...)` syntax (often used in `INSERT` statements). In SQL Server it is allowed only in the third case (VALUES), implemented in version 2008.

Other DBMSs (Postgres, Oracle, DB2) have implemented this syntax, fully or partially.